# Local stroage with global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am doing quiz show. If the user knows the questions, his money and his score will increase.
At first, I gave them money and a score. you know. and I keep the score and the money in the local depot. but when the game is reopened the money and score will be my first defined value. how do I prevent it?

```
var cnt=1000;
var score = 0;
```

cnt and score are the global variables.
I use local storage.

```
 localStorage.setItem("score ", score );
 localStorage.setItem("cnt", cnt);
```

When you give the right answer,

```
if (deger == crntUserr) {
    DevExpress.ui.dialog.alert('Correct');
    cnt = cnt + 100;
    score = score + 10;
}
```

I do not want it to have an initial value

Comment: you need to store the updated value in the localstorage?

Comment: By _the game is reopened_ what do you mean exactly? Browser restart? Application Logout/Login?

Comment: @vahdet yes application logout

Comment: @zabusa yes ı need to store the updated value in the local storage. the scores in the games always change but the score in my game is always zero. so when you close and start the game, the score is reset

Answer (score 0):

You should start the app while immediately reading your localStorage.

```
var cnt = Number(localStorage.getItem('cnt')) || 1000;
var score = Number(localStorage.getItem('score')) || 0;
```

off course upon stopping the application or onChange

```
if (deger == crntUserr) {
    DevExpress.ui.dialog.alert('Correct');
    cnt = cnt + 100;
    score = score + 10;

    // store the new value
    localStore.setItem('cnt', cnt);
    localStore.setItem('score', score);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never update your localStorage value, so when restart app, they still have initial value so change your function to this :

```
if (deger == crntUserr) {
    DevExpress.ui.dialog.alert('Correct');

    var cntStorage= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cnt'));
    var scoreStorage= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('score'));

    cnt = cntStorage + 100;
    score = scoreStorage + 10;

    localStorage.setItem('cnt', JSON.stringify(cnt));
    localStorage.setItem('score', JSON.stringify(score));
}
```

Comment: I do not want it to have an initial value. I tried but still the same